# Calculating the difference between two values in subsequent rows in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have data that looks like this:

```
Event      Time
    A  10:59:36
    B  11:00:27
    A  11:01:36
    B  11:02:01
    A  11:02:15
    B  11:02:45
```

I need to calculate the time between two events A and B. So desired output is:

```
A-B   Time Spent
  1           51
  2           25
....
```

I believe this can be done using R, but I'm a beginner to Statistics & R so finding it a bit difficult.

Comment: What format is your `Time` column in?  Does it actually look like what you have above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what type is your current `Time` column, so I used your raw data as a string and then converted it using `strptime()`.  After that, I simply took the difference of the rows for the `A` and `B` events.

```
events <- data.frame(Event=c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
                     Time=c("10:59:36", "11:00:27", "11:01:36",
                            "11:02:01", "11:02:15", "11:02:45"))

events$Time <- strptime(events$Time, format="%H:%M:%S")
output      <- events[events$Event=="B", "Time"] -
                       events[events$Event=="A", "Time"]
events_out  <- data.frame("A-B" = c(1:length(output)), 
                            "Time Spent" = output)

> events_out
  A.B Time.Spent
1   1    51 secs
2   2    25 secs
3   3    30 secs
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Now my problem is that there are some errors in the data such that sometimes an Event A is again followed by an event A. When this happens, it throws off the algorithm.

Comment: @nef  You are asked to provide a sample of your data, including what you describe here: event A followed by event A. This case doesn't exist in your question.

Comment: @Pascal I asked that he open a new question, because otherwise this entire question will turn into a big mess.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  It would closed as duplicate, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `chron`.  I took the data from the above post by @TimBiegeleisen

```
library(chron)
v1 <- chron(times(events$Time))
Time.Spent <- as.numeric(difftime(v1[c(FALSE, TRUE)], 
                    v1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], units='secs'))
newEvent <- data.frame(`A-B` = seq_along(Time.Spent), 
               Time.Spent, check.names=FALSE)
newEvent
#   A-B Time.Spent
#1   1         51
#2   2         25
#3   3         30
```